# Seeking help with a matrix optimization problem involving matrix exponentiation

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

I'm working on an optimization problem where I need to find matrices $P$, $Q$, and $C$ that minimize the norm of the difference between a given matrix $A$ and another matrix defined as $e^{P(Q + Q^T - C)P^{-1}}$. $P$ and $Q$ are real valued matrices. $C$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative real number elements. The problem is formulated as follows:

$$\underset{P,Q,C}{\min} \| e^{P\left( Q+Q^{T} -C\right) P^{-1}} -A\|_F ^2 $$

I'm struggling with figuring out the appropriate optimization methods for this problem, especially due to the complexity introduced by matrix exponentiation.

Has anyone worked on similar optimization problems or could provide insights on the best approach and suggest suitable optimization algorithms for this problem?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Shahriar Akbar Sakib

Comment: Over which set do $P$ and $Q$ vary, in your minimum?

Comment: The elements of $P$ and $Q$ are real numbers. Sorry, needed to mention it in the question.

Comment: Without any other constraints? So $Q+Q^T-C$ can be an arbitrary symmetric matrix? That seems to make the problem trivial, unless I am missing something.

Comment: There is no other constraint, $C$ is a diagonal matrix with *positive* real numbers. This ensures that the eigenvalues of $Q+Q^T-C$ lie in negative real part of the complex plane.

Comment: I must be missing something. For instance, $Q=C=1$ gives the positive value $1$, which is not in the left half-plane. More generally, $Q=(a+1)/2, C=1$ gives an arbitrary real $a$.